# Error: no matches for kind "ScaledObject" in version "keda.k8s.io/v1alpha1" in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, helm3

I am running the following command,

```
helm install airflow \
    --set executor=CeleryExecutor \
    --set workers.keda.enabled=true \
    --set workers.persistence.enabled=false \
    --namespace airflow \
    astronomer/airflow
```

which is resulting in this error:

```
Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "ScaledObject" in version "keda.k8s.io/v1alpha1"
```

Comment: Looks like you try to use a CRD (ScaledObject) that you have not installed. Have you installed Keda? https://keda.sh/docs/1.4/deploy/